# Разделить массив с объектами на несколько

Tags: javascript

От БД получаю массив с объектами.
Каждый объект в массиве имеет ключ `id` и `groupwith`, `id` - это порядковый номер, `groupwith` - это номер `id` с которым текущий элемент нужно сгруппировать.
Eсли `groupwith == 0`, группировать не нужно, просто перенести в массив с не группируемыми значениями.
Необходимо разделить данный массив на `n` массивов, в котором `n` - это число уникальных массивов с одинаковым `groupwith`.
Или все массивы в массив с различными ключами.

Comment: для группировки используй [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Что у вас не получается? Приведите ваш код.

Comment: Кода нет, пробовал через цикл, но там такое получилось что страшно показывать. Изучаю вариант с reduce, но там только соседние элементы как я понимаю. Вероятно map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, Вы имели ввиду это?

```js
let db = [{id: 1, groupwith: 2}, {id: 2, groupwith: 2}, {id: 3, groupwith: 4}, {id: 4, groupwith: 2}, {id: 5, groupwith: 0}, {id: 6, groupwith: 2}, {id: 7, groupwith: 4}];

console.info(Object.values(db.reduce((acc, c) => (c.groupwith in acc ? acc[c.groupwith].push(c) : acc[c.groupwith] = [c], acc), {})));
```

Comment: Да именно это! Спасибо! Не могу апвойтить пока к сожалению.